# Installing MicroK8S on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: microk8s

**Purpose**: Using Ubuntu installed in WSL2  as a development env for Cloud Native Apps.

**Required installation**: MicroK8S, which requires systemd, snap

**References**:

1. https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-wsl-enable-systemd
2. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/

**WSL Version**:

```
WSL version: 0.70.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.68.1
WSLg version: 1.0.45
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22000.1098
```

**Results** (after applying the references):

1. `~# ps -ef`

   ```
   root           1       0  0 16:22 ?        00:00:02 /sbin/init  # I think this should be systemd
   ```
2. `~#  sudo snap install microk8s --classic`

   ```
   Interacting with snapd is not yet supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux.
   This command has been left available for documentation purposes only.
   ```

What is wrong / missing

Thanks in advance.

Ali

**
**: I had tried 20.04 and 22.04 before by addding wsl.conf with
[boot]
systemd=true

Comment: As it says, interacting with snapd is not yet supported in WSL. Use regular Ubuntu instead.

Comment: If systemd is enabled then snapd works according to the refs i given above. (  windows 10/Ubuntu 20.04 works with  https://youtu.be/cWlYe0CE2iU )

Comment: Finally! ( But not in the way proposed by the official references given above. Perhaps I am doing something wrong)  Ubuntu Version:  22.04 . Apply https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script/tree/4d221c4f9bf89187eee7cd7ee298e5344190b191 but replace -a with -m -p as advised by pablorq (https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script/issues/36)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [WSL 299](https://github.com/ubuntu/WSL/issues/299#issuecomment-1291650396). Snap won't work with Ubuntu 22.10, you will need to wait for snapd 2.57.5+22.10 to be released. You can wait or downgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to install multi-node cluster in same host.
STEP-1 lxd init : all default except "Name of the new storage pool"
STEP-2
node-1: lxc lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 k8sn1
node-2: lxc lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 k8sw1
node-3: lxc lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 k8sw2
STEP-3:
lxc exec k8sn1 bash
run script from https://github.com/pablorq/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script ( after changing enter-systemd-namespace script -a -> -m -p)
STEP-4:
Restart and repeat 
STEP-5:
ps -ef: systemd enabled , snapd , lxd ok!
STEP-6:
sudo snap install microk8s --classic
From now on seems weird:

microk8s status --> microk8s is not running. Use microk8s inspect for a deeper inspection.
microk8s kubectl cluster-info --> Kubernetes control plane is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443
microk8s kubectl get all --all-namespaces -->
kube-system pod/calico-node-tdclz 1/1 Running 0 98s
kube-system pod/calico-kube-controllers-f4c5ffbdc-xfxfc 1/1 Running 0 98s

NAMESPACE NAME TYPE CLUSTER-IP EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S) AGE
default service/kubernetes ClusterIP 10.152.183.1 443/TCP 105s

NAMESPACE NAME DESIRED CURRENT READY UP-TO-DATE AVAILABLE NODE SELECTOR
AGE
kube-system daemonset.apps/calico-node 1 1 1 1 1 kubernetes.io/os=linux 104s

NAMESPACE NAME READY UP-TO-DATE AVAILABLE AGE
kube-system deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers 1/1 1 1 104s

NAMESPACE NAME DESIRED CURRENT READY AGE
kube-system replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-54c85446d4 0 0 0 100s
kube-system replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-f4c5ffbdc 1 1 1 98s

I think it is time to give up using wsl as a development environment for kubernetes.

### Notes:
host and lxc have the same Ubuntu version, 20.04

lxc storage list -->
NAME | DRIVER | SOURCE | DESCRIPTION | USED BY | STATE |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------+
| iot-lab | btrfs | /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/disks/iot-lab.img | | 3 | CREATED

lxc network list -->

eth0 | physical | NO | | | | 0 | |
+--------+----------+---------+---------------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+---------+
| lxdbr0 | bridge | YES | 10.25.76.1/24 | fd42:e2dc:d3f6:4774::1/64 | | 2 | CREATED |
+--------+----------+---------+---------------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+---------